# Django, select image from previous uploaded images

Tags: django, django-forms, imagefield, django-filebrowser

I have a Post model which has a ImageField.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lead = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="posts", blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
```

In my ModelForm, the file input for the image works perfectly, but I was wondering how to let the user choose between uploading a new image, or selecting one from all the images that have been previously uploaded to the site.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that define another model `Image` and then create a foreign key from `Post` to `Image`. When creating a new post, you can either select an existing image or upload a new one and then select it.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but then the input will render as as select. How can I show the users a thumbnail of the image?

Comment: Create a specific widget that does so. :)